# How to serve a sitemap.xml using reverse proxy in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy

Due to business requirements, I need to create a new sitemap, every time a new page is added in the admin panel. We're using Heroku, so we looked into the [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem to do this. We are uploading the sitemap every time the `rake sitemap:refresh` is called.

But the sitemap needs to be inside our domain such as `https://example.org/sitemap.xml`. So we decided to use reverse proxy (with [rack-reverse-proxy](https://github.com/jaswope/rack-reverse-proxy) gem)

in our config.ru we have

```
use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy '/sitemap.xml', 'http://our-bucket.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml', :timeout => 15000,   :preserve_host => true
end
```

and our robots.txt file is

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /admin
```

But when we submit in google webmaster tools, I get an error, saying `URL restricted by robots.txt`, when I try to access directly in the browser `https://our_domain.com/sitemap.xml` I get an

```
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
  <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
```

but accessing the s3 link, `http://our-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml` our sitemap.xml is displayed correctly.

Any ideas? Is what we're attempting to do even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue because I was on a system that was behind Basic Auth, and so it was passing along that header, which S3 did not like.

Resolved mine by updating reverse_proxy to this latest commit (for some reason the setting I needed didn't make it into the latest release tag):

```
gem 'rack-reverse-proxy', require: 'rack/reverse_proxy', git: 'https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy.git', ref: 'a4f28a6'
```

and adding the following setting to reverse_proxy:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::ReverseProxy do
  reverse_proxy_options stripped_headers: ['Authorization']
  ... <rules here>
end
```

This question was old but hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an action that responds as xml like so `app/controllers/sitemap_controller.rb`:

```
  layout false
  def index
    @my_pages = Pages.all
    render formats: :xml
  end
```

And correspondent view file `app/views/sitemap/index.xml.builder`:

```
base_url = request.url.chomp('sitemap.xml')

xml.instruct! :xml, version: '1.0', encoding: 'utf-8'

xml.tag! 'urlset',
  'xmlns' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
  'xmlns:xsi' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  'xsi:schemaLocation' => 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
   http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd' do

     @my_pages.each do |page|
       xml.url {
         xml.loc URI.join(base_url, page.url)
       }
     end
  end
```

Don't forget to create a route for it:
`config/routes.rb`:

```
    get '/sitemap.xml', to: 'sitemap#index'
```

No need for reverse proxy, you could also create an rake task to ping search engines and you're good to go.
Happy coding!